# Contact Form: user not returned to the form after Submit

Tags: php, contact-form

When a user has clicked on SUBMIT button on Contact Form, success or error message does not show up on the bottom part of the  Contact form; instead the message is displayed on a new blank page in a plain format and then it terminates; the user is not returned to the Contact Form. I have these three files for the contact form: `contactus.html, style.css`, and `emailform.php`.

The emailform php (this php resides on the host server) contains the  `if ($_POST['submit']) {` code for error trapping. `Contactus.html` contains

`<form method="post" action="http://www.xxxxxx.com/emailform.php" name="Form" id="Form">`.

Can anyone help fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: upload your mail sending code too

Comment: Please format your question so that it is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

If after submitting the form you want to send the user back to the previous page your `emailform.php` file should contain:

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

If you want to display an error message on `contactus.html` you could add a parameter to the url let's say `contactus.html?error=1`, there you can capture the error and display it to the user within the same page.

Alternatively your `contactus.html` file could do an AJAX request to `emailform.php` and display the result within the same page so the browser doesn't need to redirect to `emailform.php`.

If you have included jQuery and want to do the POST via AJAX try removing the `action=...` from your form, make you your head includes jQuery and past this anywhere within your body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#submit").on("click",function(){

    var email = $("#email").val();
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/emailform.php",
        data: { email : email, name : name, message: message }
    }).done(function(msg) {
        //update your message div here
        $("#message").test(msg);
        alert(msg);
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: >If you want to display an error message on contactus.html you could add

Comment: I do not understand what code to add in my following contactus.html? 

  <form method="post" action="http://www.xxxxxx.com/email.php" name="Form" id="Form">
    <label>Your Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" maxlength="40" placeholder="Name">
    <label>Your Email</label>
    <input id="email" type="email" name="email" maxlength="40"  placeholder="You@MailHost.com">
    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea id="message" name="message" maxlength="1500" placeholder="Type Here"></textarea>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

Comment: @sjhawar I've just updated my answer, should now be as simple as copy and paste ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Please guide me as to "your header includes jQuery".

Comment: @sjhawar right, jQuery is a JavaScript library which will allow you to use the code above, on the head of `contactus.html` file, that is inside the tags `<head>...</head>` paste this line of code `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` then everything should work.

Comment: I have copied both script you gave; Do I need to make any change in the following code?:
<form method="post" action="http://www.domainname.com/emailform.php" name="Form" id="Form">

Comment: I just tested by filling out contact form in contactus.html; still not returning to contactus.html after displaying success or error. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I solved the problem of redirecting by using the following code in my emailform.php file residing at my webserver:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;URL=index.html">
</head>

Comment: Is the following method preferred? header( "refresh:5; url=index.html" ); //wait for 5 seconds before redirecting

Comment: I wouldn't use that, you won't get what you want with it. simply change your from tag `<form method="post" action="domainname.com/emailform.php"; name="Form" id="Form">` to just `<form>`

Answer (score 0):

Do a redirect from your emailform.php back to the contactus.html.
If you want to be able to react to the form, make the contactus a php-file (if your webserver is not configured to work with php in html files).

You can send a get-parameter via url to the contactus when you are redirecting from emailform.php. `With header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '?success=true');`

In your contactus.php you can check if there is a parameter etc.

```
if(isset($_GET['success'])){
    if($_GET['success'] === 'true'){
        echo 'it worked fine';
    else{
        echo 'something did not work';
    }
}
```

Comment: My webserver is hostmonster where my emailform.php resides. Before I upload my contactus.html with its style.css to my said webserver, I am testing the contactus.html on my windows 8.1 laptop computer (text editor: dreamweaver). No success yet!

Comment: Could you give the code to put in emailform.php to redirect back to the contactus.html after displaying success or error.

Comment: You don't have to display the success/error message on the emailform.php, you can just redirect via header(); after you did your other stuff your script is currently doing. You can put my if-structure into your contactus.html, though you should turn your contactus.html into contactus.php so the php-part gets interpreted

Comment: I solved the problem of redirecting by using the following code in my emailform.php file residing at my webserver:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;URL=index.html">
</head>